# Can Isobaric compression increase the internal energy of an ideal gas?

Tags: thermodynamics

When an ideal gas is compressed isobarically the given energy by the external source is let out as heat alongwith some more heat that comes from the decreement of internal energy.
My question is why doesnt the energy given by the external source increases the internal energy and some lets out some heat??
Maybe I am missing something conceptually about so please help.

Comment: It is only by mathematical computation, can we hope to obtain the results of comparing the energy input by work done v.s. the energy output by heat transfer, and conclude that isobaric compression reduces the internal energy of an ideal gas. This computation is quite simple, and so should not be avoided. Of course, an argument via the ideal gas law is even easier and faster, but that does not detract from what I am saying here. If this ratio behaviour is not fixed, then you cannot claim that it is an isobaric process. It is thus unclear what it is you are asking for.

Comment: If the pressure is held constant and the volume decreases, you have to remove heat to lower the temperature.  Internal energy decreases with decreasing temperature.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a consequence of 1 st law of Thermodynamics,

> dU = dQ + dW
> (Heat added is +ve and Work done by system is -ve)

Cases when dU is +ve

- dQ and dW both are +ve (1)
- dQ is +ve dW is -ve, |dQ|>|dW| (2)
- dQ is -ve dW is +ve, |dW|>|dQ| (3)

Cases when dU is -ve

- dQ and dW both are -ve (4)
- dQ is +ve dW is -ve, |dQ|<|dW| (5)
- dQ is -ve dW is +ve, |dW|<|dQ| (6)

Cases when dU is zero

- dQ is +ve dW is -ve, |dQ|=|dW| (7)
- dQ is -ve dW is +ve, |dW|=|dQ| (8)

In our case

dW = pdV = -ve (since dV is -ve)

dQ = CpdT = -ve (since dT is -ve by PV=RT)

So it's case (4)
Hence dU is -ve .

Hope it helps...

Comment: Please format your answer in MathJax. As it stands it is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

For a reversible isobaric compression of an ideal gas the following holds true

$\frac{V}{T}$=constant

It follows that a reduction in volume results in a reduction in temperature. Since the internal energy of an ideal gas depends only on temperature, it follows that an isobaric compression results in a decrease in internal energy.

In terms of the first law for an isobaric compression, the energy leaving the system in the form of heat is greater than the energy entering the system in the form of work.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention in question that some heat is given out,you must consider the walls of container of gas are ideal **diathermics**,which means Heat can Exchange freely between Surrounding and container-gas system, The answer given By @BobD is sufficient,
Here is a bit More about it

Whenever gas is compressed in adiabatic container,It is impossible to maintain constant temperature as well as pressure at same time,Either temperature must decrease or pressure must increase according to ideal gas law

If pressure is to be kept constant,The walls must be diathermal

In diathermal container and Ideal gas compression using isobaric process

Internal energy **tends** to decrease, due to decrease temperature of gas, but surrounding interaction with walls Continuously Exchange heat to maintain Equilibrium between Gas temperature and Surrounding temperature,In this process, The Work,which should have otherwise converted to Internal energy if Diathermic walls were not present. Now, Gets converted to Heat exchange between Surrounding and wall of container, As a result,external work converts to hear exchange between Surrounding and container

Note: Internal energy depends only on Temperature,

Also,To maintain contant **pressure**, Extra internal energy as compared to initial state must be converted to Heat exchange,this Leads to Increase in Temperature of surrounding

You can say,Surrounding acts as sink, I. e it can take A lot of heat for small changes in its temperature